# What is the single most compelling reason to migrate to Spring 3 from 2.x

Tags: java, spring

Currently working on a Spring 2.5 web application, looks as if the business has at least a 5+ year plan for it's usage.

There isn't anything in terms of a technology roadmap in place for the app.

Comment: Why not wait and port to Spring 5.0 instead of to 3.0, then 4.0 and then 5.0. look at all the features I can get implemented in the code instead.

Comment: took me a week or so to move a big spring app from 256 to 3x. That included changing things that still worked to 3-style code. If you were working with 3, when the next version or exciting feature came out you could get it with very little effort. sticking with 256 means the effort gap will increase the longer you leave it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring 2.5.6 is stable, and working smoothly. Staying with it won't be a mistake.

Spring 3 gives [additional features](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/02/25/spring-framework-30-m2-released/) and support for newer JavaEE specifications. I wouldn't say it gives something extraordinary.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Bozho's answer.  One significant new Spring core feature that isn't mentioned in the page linked is the Expression Language feature, which allows you to do a variety of things in XML wiring files that previously had to be implemented as custom code.

SpringSecurity in 3.0 is a mixed bag.  On the one hand, there are new features and improvements to existing ones.  On the other hand, they have broken source code compatibility in a lot of areas.  People who cannot do everything with the SpringSecurity namespaces and the standard classes may be in for some head scratching, recoding, and in some cases pain.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo generates spring 3 based applications. Not immediately applicable to existing apps, but it's great to be able to compare roo's best-practice output, and if you were 3.x based then you could copy roo config / code output into your existing application to get functionality for free.